# Cant figure out conditionals

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a 30 day of code challenge and passed 5/8 tests on my code and can't figure out the reason it keeps failing

The parameters are that 
if N is odd print weird, 
if N is even and in the range of 2-5 print not weird
if N is even and in the range of 6-20 print weird
if N is even and greater than 20 print not weird

```
N = int(input())

if  N % 2 == 0 and range(2-5): 
    print("Not Weird")
elif N % 2 == 0 and range(6-20): 
    print("Weird")
elif N % 2 == 0 and N > 20:
    print("Not Weird")
elif N % 2 == 1 :
    print("Weird")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if  N % 2 == 0 and range(2-5):
```

does not do what you think, it should instead be something like:

```
if  N % 2 == 0 and N in range(2, 6):
```

Specifically:

- each sub-condition (on either side of your 'and') should be complete.
- range, in your example, was range(-3) since that's what 2-5 gives.
- the range is half open, meaning it includes the start but excludes the end.

Answer (score 1):

1) The function `range` with defined begging and end is a function that takes 2 parameters as argument. Therefore I'd recommend you to use it as `range(x,y)` instead of `range(x-y)`.

If you use it like `range(2-5)`, you're actually asking for `range(-3)`. When used with only 1 arg, the function `range` will give you a list of `int` **from 0 up to the input arg**.

Regarded that there is no integer **greater than 0 *and* less than -3**, then you're getting an empty list.

2) Also, notice that the upper limit is not inclusive:

```
>>> for i in range(2,5):
...     print(i)
... 
2
3
4
```

so you might consider to use `range(2,6)` for the first case, `range(6,21)` for the second case and so on and so forth..

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @paxdiablo's answer, you can also use the `step` argument of `range` to test for even numbers:

```
if N in range(2, 6, 2):
```